# Calling .all in Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, methods

I'm building an Active Record query over a few lines:

```
query = ForumThread.joins(:posts)
query = query.where(:posts => {:some_integer => 123})
```

No query is executed for `results = query`. However `results = query.all` works. **What does call .all on the ActiveRecord::Relation do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
results = query
```

all you are doing is making results equal to the query object.

When you call

```
results = query.all
```

You are sending the all method to query (which says get all of the records that match the query) and assigning the result to results.